# Function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node application i am using function.But i am getting the result of that function:

My code:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',  
  user     : 'xxxx',
  password : 'xxxxx',
  database : 'xxxxxxx',
  debug : true,
})
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");
    } else if ( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

 if(level5 == undefined)
{
   var result1=querylevel5();
   console.log("vvvvvvvvv="+result1)
   res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   res.end(JSON.stringify(result1,null,"\n"));
}
```

My function:

```
    function querylevel5()
    {
      var result;    
      connection.query("select * from levels ", function(err, row1, fields) {
        result= row1;
        /*res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(row1,null,"\n"));*/
      });
      return result;
    }
```

I want to get the row1 result ,in my calling function..But its printing "undefined"..I am new to this node.js..So please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Besides, I don't know how we're supposed to help you without knowing what `connection` is.

Comment: K wait i will update my question..

Comment: My guess: `connection.query` is part of e.g. `node-mysql` or another sql module. So most likely it is an async call, so the callback function is not called at the time where you do the `return result;`

Comment: Thanks @t.niese ..What i have to modify to achieve this..

Comment: @Subburaj look at the answer of `Joachim Pileborg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the function `querylevel5` returns immediately before `result`. You have to do like most any other node.js framework does, like for example the `connection.query` function, namely use callbacks:

```
if(level5 == undefined) {
    querylevel5(function(result) {
        console.log("vvvvvvvvv="+result)
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result,null,"\n"));
    });
}
```

And

```
function querylevel5(callback) {
    connection.query("select * from levels ", function(err, row1, fields) {
        callback(row1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the result is delivered in a callback (i.e. asynchronously), but you are calling the method synchronously and printing the result - so the result hasn't actually been returned by the time you try to print it.